# Yii: introduce DEV and PROD environments

Tags: php, yii, development-environment, production-environment

I would like to write Yii code, which differs on DEV and PROD environments. For example, on PROD I would like application to send real e-mails, while on DEV write everything to file or send to local mailbox.

Also it would be nice to have db profiling enabled on DEV and disabled on PROD.

Is there a way to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this extension could help you:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-environment/

Comment: We are using this exact extension for a multi server website and it works pretty well. We have four environments and we have made some changes here and there but overall it's running great.

Comment: This is actually how the configuration is implemented in Yii2. A whole lot less effort. It is done by simply merging all configs in your index.php, so this can easily be backported.

Answer (score 0):

Have a config file that differs and let all other sources be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I just include different config files based on the host that include the basic (common) config.

An example that overrides the db password for a specific environment:

`index.php`:

```
$configFile = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '.php';
if ($configFile == '.php') $configFile = 'main.php';
$configFile = "$baseDir/config/$configFile";
$app = Yii::createWebApplication($configFile);
$app->run();
```

`main.php`:

```
return array(
   ...
   'components' => array(
      'db' => array(
        'connectionString'            => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
        'username'                    => 'some_user',
        'password'                    => 'some_password',
      )
   )
);
```

`production.server.com.php`:

```
// Include common config
$config = require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/main.php');
// Remove whatever we don't need here (obviously optional)
unset($config['components']['...']);

return CMap::mergeArray(
   $config,
   array(
      'components' => array(
         'db' => array(
            'password' => 'alternative_production_password'
         )
      )
   )
);
```

So basically this gives you a custom config file based on the server host. 
Obviously if you use this you should verify the host name and whether the config exists.

You could also use other things (like a define for the environment or so).

The basic principle remains the same:
The "final" config file includes the common configuration, removes unneeded things (if applicable) and defines an array structure that only contains what needs to be changed. This structure is merged with the common config to result in the final configuration.